# in jpa and hibernate annotions how to save record with one to one ralationship

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

Thanks for your replies here i got the other problems here see the senario

for example I have two tables like

1)BOOKBASICDETAILS 
2)BOOKOTHERDETAILS

```
@Entity @TABLE(bookDetails) 
class Book{ 
  @Id private Long bookId; // in mycase it is not generated value it assigned programtically 
  private String name;
  @OnetoOne @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn 
  private BookOtherDetails bookOtherInfo;
 // more code 
}  
@Entity 
@Table(bookOhterDetails) 
class BookOtherInfo{
   @Id
   private Long bookId;// same as bookId in Book
   private String authorName;
  // more details  
}
```

In this case data is not inserted into BookOtherDetails table.Any suggestion are valuable

Thanks in future

Answer (score 0):

> In other case if it is existing value from city table already cityId
>   is there in my jsp ,there is no need to inser into city table and
>   genrate new cityid , i can insert existing cityid into enrollment
>   detail

That's no `OneToOne` Relationship, because a city can be related to many enrollments as i understood. You have to use a `@ManyToOne` relationship instead.

Comment: Thank u Biswas.Worthfull point.even in that case also is it posssible to handle mycase.Actually i confused in this case.Now i will remodify my code.

Comment: Thanks for your replies here i got the other doubt,see the situtation